# How to use BOM file with Maven?

Tags: maven, jboss

I have done considerable research in internet and I haven't found any easy explanation what to do with `BOM` files with Maven.

The problem is that I use JBoss 7.1.1 and I want to include all JBoss client jars in `pom.xml`. JBoss has a manual that says that I should use BOM files, but I don't know how to use it in my `pom.xml`.

Please help.

Comment: Do you, by any chance, mean .pom file? Can you provide a link to this manual?

Answer (score 154):

A `bom` is a so called **bill of materials** - it bundles several dependencies to assure that the versions will work together. JBoss has boms for many of it's projects, including [Arquillian](http://arquillian.org/) and the [JBoss AS](http://www.jboss.org/jbossas) itself.

There is an explanation of the `bom` usage in [the maven docs](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html) - it is hidden well below.

A practical example:

You include the bom into your pom like this:

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.bom</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-javaee-6.0-with-tools</artifactId>
            <version>${javaee6.with.tools.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

Then you do not have to specify the version attribute of a dependency, if it is defined in the `bom` like this:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.enterprise</groupId>
    <artifactId>cdi-api</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: In fact once you install Jboss you can find

   jboss-eap-6.0\bin\client\jboss-client.jar

In the same folder there is readme.txt

    C:\jboss-eap-6.0\bin\client\README.txt

Comment: @Reddymails - yeah, this is probably the very manual the OP was not sure how to interpret. Good find.

Comment: By the way, another useful pointer : [Maven and JBoss: how to use BOMs to keep releases in sync](http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-maven/maven-and-jboss-how-to-use-boms)