# How to find the Maven dependency compatibility of Hibernate and Spring?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven, dependencies

I am facing difficulty for dependencies related issue like:

I have created a spring project in **4.1.1.RELEASE** version. Now i want to use hibernate dependency for spring version **4.1.1.RELEASE**.

But which version of hibernate dependency is compatible with above version of spring? Is there any site for compatibility checking or anything else? Please help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend to use the same versions that are used by Spring Boot. (I do not mean that you should use Spring-Boot, just use the same set of dependencies/versions).

Spring Boot has some kind ob [BOM-depencency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14874966/how-to-use-bom-file-with-maven), that contains the dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.3.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

*The current version of spring-boot: 1.2.3.RELEASE uses Spring 4.1.6.RELEASE, so you must maybe search for one boot that is a bit older.*

Even `Spring-Boot` `1.2.0.RELEASE` use Spring `4.1.3.RELEASE` - so you Either update to Spring >= 4.1.3. or you ignore this version mismatch.

After you have chosen the rigth Spring-Boot Version: You either check out this file and search for the version number you need, or you import it in to your `pom.xml`, and the omit the explicit `version` attribute in your hibernate-dependency>

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.3.RELEASE</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement> 
...
<dependencies>
    <dependency>     
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <!-- version is taken from the bom -->
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: How do i know which version of Spring-Boot support   4.1.1.RELEASE version of spring?

Comment: Go to Maven-Central: search for spring-boot-dependencies, open the pom for 1.2.3, 1.2.2. 1.2.1, 1.2.0 (...), search within the pom for: `<spring.version>`

Comment: Even Spring-Boot 1.2.0.RELEASE use Spring 4.1.3.RELEASE - so you Either update to Spring >= 4.1.3. or you ignore this version mismatch.

Comment: The Spring-Boot uses 4.0.9.RELEASE  or  4.1.3.RELEASE but not 4.1.1.RELEASE version. Why spring 4.1.1.RELEASE version not exist in spring-boot?

Comment: Can i ask you one more question?

Comment: Spring-Boot and Spring(core) are two asynchronous projects - so there is no Boot for each  Spring(core)

Comment: you can use springs bom instead of spring boots, https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#overview-maven-bom

Comment: @mdo: the spring-framework-bom contains only spring-framework modues (spring-beans, spring-context, spring-web, spring-test, spring-orm...) but does not contain references for hibernate or any libary other than spring.

Comment: What did they do before Spring Boot? Why don't they simply have a webpage showing which versions are compatible? That would be much easier than searching maven central and reading POMs.

Answer (score 3):

You can simply run:

```
mvn dependency:tree
```

And then look for `org.hiberante` dependencies inherited from the spring modules. That's how you can tell which Spring version uses a certain Hibernate dependency.

Comment: After running this command "mvn dependency:tree" in project directory it's getting error.

Comment: Here is the error...............


[ERROR] Could not find goal '' in plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.8 among available goals copy, analyze, unpack, list-repositories, resolve, resolve-plugins
, build-classpath, list, analyze-dep-mgt, sources, analyze-duplicate, copy-dependencies, unpack-dependencies, go-offline, get, purge-local-repository, properties, analyze-report, tre
e, analyze-only, help -> [Help 1]

Comment: ya but if you have transitive dependencies you can exclude and exclude and exclude until you get to the root dependency you're looking for