# Can't add dependency to pom.xml file

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I am following a Springboot tutorial on a website I found. The site tells us to add various dependencies to our pom.xml file. I added the web and thymeleaf dependencies through the Spring Initializr. Hwoever, I realized that I forgot to add the security dependency. When I try to edit my code and add the security dependency by typing:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
        <artifactId>reactor-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: Whats the actual error or problem you're seeing?

Comment: I thought I added it to the original post, my bad. This is the error: Dependency 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security:<unknown>' not found more... (Ctrl+F1)

Comment: Are you using `spring-boot-starter-parent` as the parent in your own?

Comment: I believe is, here is the rest of my code from the pom.xml file. 
 <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
 <parent>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
  <version>2.1.7.RELEASE</version>
  <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
 </parent>
 <groupId>springtest</groupId>
 <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
 <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
 <name>spring-boot-starter</name>
 <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

 <properties>
  <java.version>11</java.version>
 </properties>

Comment: Can you update the question with the full POM? Comments don't support multiline formatting so it's difficult to piece it all together.

Comment: Also, what happens if you try to generate a new starter app on spring initializer and include security, does that work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should either [inherit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14876651/750510) your project from `spring-boot-starter-parent`:

```xml
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.7.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
```

The parent project provides the following features:

- Java 1.8 as the default compiler level.
- UTF-8 source encoding.
- A [Dependency Management section](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-build-systems.html#using-boot-dependency-management), inherited from the spring-boot-dependencies pom, that manages the versions of common dependencies. **This dependency management lets you omit `<version>` tags for those dependencies when used in your own `pom`.**
- An execution of the [`repackage` goal](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.7.RELEASE/maven-plugin/repackage-mojo.html) with a `repackage` execution id.
- Sensible [resource filtering](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html).
- Sensible plugin configuration ([exec plugin](https://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/), [Git commit ID](https://github.com/ktoso/maven-git-commit-id-plugin), and [shade](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/)).
- Sensible resource filtering for `application.properties` and `application.yml` including profile-specific files (for example, `application-dev.properties` and `application-dev.yml`)

Or [use](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-build-systems.html#using-boot-maven-without-a-parent) the `spring-boot-dependencies` [BOM](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14876651/750510):

```xml
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <!-- Import dependency management from Spring Boot -->
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.7.RELEASE</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

Using the BOM is the way to go when you would not like to inherit from the `spring-boot-starter-parent` POM. You may have your own corporate standard parent that you need to use or you may prefer to explicitly declare all your Maven configuration. You would still keep the benefit of the dependency management, but not the plugin management.

Both solutions will allow you to omit versions of Spring dependencies.