# Unit tests fails with IllegalArgumentException due to aws region cant be found

Tags: java, spring, amazon-web-services, maven

I had a working spring boot application including unit tests. But when I added AmazonSimpleEmailService feature to project, Spring application works without a problem and sends emails, however unit tests running with `mvn clean install` throws exception:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.cloud.aws.core.region.StaticRegionProvider]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The region '' is not a valid region!
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The region '' is not a valid region!
```

Note that I added aws-config.xml :

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:aws-context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/cloud/aws/context"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.1.xsd
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/cloud/aws/context
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/cloud/aws/context/spring-cloud-aws-context-1.0.xsd">

  <aws-context:context-credentials>
    <aws-context:simple-credentials access-key="${cloud.aws.credentials.accessKey:}" secret-key="${cloud.aws.credentials.secretKey:}"/>
  </aws-context:context-credentials>

  <aws-context:context-region region="${cloud.aws.region.static:}"/>
</beans>
```

And this configuration in application.yml file:

```
cloud:
  aws:
    stack:
      auto: false
    region:
      static: us-west-2
      auto: false
    credentials:
      accessKey: __SomeAccessKey__
      secretKey: __SomeSecretKey__
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

**Configuring region:**
Like for the credentials, the Spring Cloud AWS module also supports the configuration of the region inside the Spring Boot configuration files. The region can be automatically detected or explicitly configured (e.g. in case of local tests against the AWS cloud).

> cloud.aws.region.auto : true

Enables automatic region detection based on the EC2 meta data service. So make auto = true in application.yml.

**Link** : [configuring_region](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-aws/2.2.0.M2/reference/html/#_configuring_region)

Comment: Hi, I didnt make typeo here. I am sure that the region is us-west-2 and I have given correct configuration in application.yml. The code works perfectly with Spring application, sending mails successfully. The problem is at unit tests.

Comment: The answer is updated and I hope this will be your solution.

Comment: It doesn't solve the problem. I have already given the region with:
cloud.aws.region.static

Comment: Bro, did you try region.auto = true?

Comment: Then maybe, it's something spring version issue which doesn't support this region. Let me try to find something useful for you.

Comment: You are missing the point. It works perfectly when I start application with Sping Boot. Problem happens only when I run mvn clean install

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62521556/spring-boot-spring-cloud-aws-region-not-found Please See this one