# FasterXML Object Mapping String to LocalDateTime Issue

Tags: java, fasterxml

I have String as below,

```
value = {"name":"John","timeStamp":"2020-08-11T13:31:31"}
```

My Pojo class is,

```
@Getter
@ToString
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
class Person{
    
    private String name;    

    @JsonFormat(pattern = "YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm", shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING)
    @JsonSerialize(using = LocalDateTimeSerializer.class)
    private LocalDateTime timeStamp; 
}
```

I use the below artifact, as per https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-modules-java8

```
 <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-module-parameter-names</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jdk8</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

I use the below config,

```
 final ObjectMapper objectMapper = JsonMapper.builder()
                        .addModule(new ParameterNamesModule())
                        .addModule(new Jdk8Module())
                        .addModule(new JavaTimeModule())
                        .build();

objectMapper.readValue(value, Person.class)
```

I'm getting the below exception,

```
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter
```

I tried with the below in the timeStamp also, but no luck

```
 @JsonFormat(pattern = "yyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss")
```

Comment: I believe that the correct format would be `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss`

Comment: Just tried with ```@JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss", shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING)``` also but no luck. :-(

Answer (score 1):

The ISO format you're showing is the default so no need to get complicated and it should work!

```java
class Person {
    private String name;    
    private LocalDateTime timeStamp; 
}
```

PS. suggest you use [jackson-bom](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson/jackson-bom/2.11.2) managed dependencies to avoid 2.11.1 appearing all over the place. See [How to use BOM file with Maven?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14874966/how-to-use-bom-file-with-maven) for a BOM example.

Comment: thank you very much for your reply. I tired with standalone program with my existing code, works good. Due to other API call, throws me an error.