# Cant find where spring-web version defined in maven

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, spring-mvc, spring-cloud

I have a project, where I use `spring-cloud-starter-stream-rabbit`. But our devOps team asked me why I'm using `spring-web`. I've figured out that spring-web goes exactly from spring-cloud-starter-stream-rabbit. But there is no version defined:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

I've started to look in parent projects. But with no result.
[pom hierarchy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W3ZFA.png)

I go from bottom to top:

[spring-cloud-stream-binder-rabbit-core.pom](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/cloud/spring-cloud-stream-binder-rabbit-core/3.1.2/spring-cloud-stream-binder-rabbit-core-3.1.2.pom)

[spring-cloud-stream-binder-rabbit-parent.pom](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/cloud/spring-cloud-stream-binder-rabbit-parent/3.1.2/spring-cloud-stream-binder-rabbit-parent-3.1.2.pom)

[spring-cloud-build.pom](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/cloud/spring-cloud-build/3.0.2/spring-cloud-build-3.0.2.pom)

Surprisingly I cant find version there. I thought maybe this versions goes from other dependencies. Created project with single dependency like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>example</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-stream-rabbit</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

But `mvn dependency:list` showed:

```
...
[INFO]    com.fasterxml:classmate:jar:1.3.4:compile
[INFO]    org.springframework:spring-web:jar:5.3.4:compile
[INFO]    javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:jar:1.3.2:compile
...
```

Wow! Where is that secret place where maven gets version for spring-web? If you know please help.

Thanks for support!

Comment: It is defined in the parent, which includes an import of a certain Spring Boot version which in turn imports the proper Spring Boot version. Just how maven works.

Comment: Thank you for answer. But i've looked in spring-boot-dependencies, and i haven't found any spring-web version. https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-dependencies/2.4.5/spring-boot-dependencies-2.4.5.pom

Comment: Correct, as it itself import the `spring-framework-bom` which contains all Spring Framework dependencies. (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14874966/how-to-use-bom-file-with-maven)