# Maven parent to child inheritance dependency not working

Tags: maven, hierarchy

below is the parent-pom.xml I have :-

```
<groupId>com.example.parent</groupId>
<artifactId>example-parent</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<name>sample-parent</name>

<dependencyManagement>
  <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
        <artifactId>testcontainers-bom</artifactId>
        <version>1.19.1</version>
        <type>pom</type>
  </dependency>
</dependencyManagement>
```

In child pom, I added below dependencies:-
child-pom.xml

```
<groupId>com.example.child</groupId>
<artifactId>example-child</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0</version>
<name>sample-child</name>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<parent>
   <groupId>com.example.parent</groupId>
   <artifactId>example-parent</artifactId>
   <version>1.0.0</version>
</parent>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
      <artifactId>testcontainers</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
      <artifactId>spock</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

But, when I am building it, getting below error:-

```
'dependencies.dependency.version' for org.testcontainers:testcontainers:jar is missing. @ com.example.child:sample-child:${revision}, C:\...\pom.xml, line 438, column 17
```

Looking at various posts here, it should work, but somehow it is not working in my case. Not sure what I am missing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add `<scope>import</scope>` to the dependency in the parent pom. See [How to use BOM file with Maven?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14874966/how-to-use-bom-file-with-maven) for further details.

Comment: This solution worked for me. This should be the accepted answer