# Cannot Import Google Cloud

Tags: java, maven, google-cloud-platform, cloud-document-ai

I am following Google's official tutorial on setting up Document AI: https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/libraries#client-libraries-install-java

My POM file:

```xml
    <project>
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    
        <groupId>com.mycompany.app</groupId>
        <artifactId>my-app</artifactId>
        <version>1</version>
    
        <dependencyManagement>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
                    <artifactId>libraries-bom</artifactId>
                    <version>26.1.3</version>
                    <type>pom</type>
                    <scope>import</scope>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
                    <artifactId>google-cloud-document-ai</artifactId>
                    <version>2.7.5</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </dependencyManagement>
    
    </project>
```

But I cannot get the imports to show up properly:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dependencyManagement` should contain only the bom, other dependencies should be under **`dependencies`**, one more point, you should not have the version for `google-cloud-document-ai` because its version should come from the bom.

example `pom.xml` below

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>io.github.ozkanpakdil</groupId>
    <artifactId>gcloud-ai</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>gcloud-ai</name>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>libraries-bom</artifactId>
                <version>26.29.0</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-cloud-document-ai</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Reference:

- [How to use BOM file with Maven?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14874966/how-to-use-bom-file-with-maven)
- https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#bill-of-materials-bom-poms